# Changing abbreviations in address column without changing the street names using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, expression, address, replace

I have two shapefiles and I want to join them based address values. The problem is that some rows provide street names along with street abbreviations, which some other rows provide street names with full form. (ex. str and street, ave and avenue, etc.) How can I convert the abbreviations to full forms without making any changes to the street names (ex: "Dr" and "Alexan*dr*ia".)

I understand that QGIS has a function called `replace()`, however I am not sure what is the correct way to write the expression.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the abbreviations are at the end of the text, the expression could be something like:

```
regexp_replace( nume,' st$',' street')
```

Comment: The abbreviations are all after the street name. (ex: 20 Flyntwood Dr, 3220 Waterway BLVD, 2729 Shawnee Dr). The abbreviations are all the last word in the column.

Comment: Then the above expression should work fine for you. Just adapt it for your abbreviations.

Comment: So I should replace all "name"s with the column name?

Comment: Yes, the `str` with your abbreviations, and `street` with the respective full word.

Comment: I tried the expression, however the if function didn't really help. It changes all strs to Street including those with in street names

Comment: This is the expression I used: if(property_d LIKE '%ST',replace(property_d, 'ST', 'STREET'),property_d)

Comment: I edited the answer.